# Data Not Displayed In Html File when calling file using ajax

Tags: html, ajax

My problem is I'm calling one dummy.php file from ajax (jQuery);
this dummy.php will call the url that is my Oracle server file which returns string data. 
My dummy.php will call url and echo data return from url.

test.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     alert('hiheloo');
              $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"oracletest/dummy.php",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            )};

</script>
<body>
<p id="content"> </p>
</body>
```

dummy.php

```
$url = "http://..my ipaddress:8082/oracle/test.php?data=2";
        $a = file_get_contents($url);
        echo ($a);
```

My dummy.php  work properly only I'm not getting data in html.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the ajax type to "Get".

Comment: Can you get the correct result if you visit the dummy.php directly?

Comment: Use firebug or Fiddler to find out what you get exactly from ajax.